# Conectar REST API con Ionic Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, api, ionic

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil usando angular, para conectarme a una base de datos utilizo una rest api basada en node js.
Me conecto a la rest api desde angular usando el HTTP CLIENT y la api rest esta subida a en heroku, funciona correctamente cuando corro el comando ionic serve y ejecuto la aplicacion en el localhost pero cuando intento usar DevApp para testear la aplicacion me da problemas la conexión concretamente el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que tu aplicación en heroku devuelve un fallo, pero sin ver el código o los logs es imposible saber qué está pasando. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir más detalles

Comment: Habilitaste las CORS???